# Catch comments with Regular expressions

Tags: php

When I write the regular expression on https://regex101.com/   \*.*?\* on dddd *ssssdedc* ddddddd I get the *ssssdedc* part.When I write this on a php file:

```
echo '<br />';
echo preg_match('/\\\*.*?\\\*/','dddd \*ssssdedc\* ddddddd',$matches);
echo '<br />';
var_dump($matches);
```

I get an empty string.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

When you do the match, the extra `\` you've included are making the strings not match.  You only need to escape things like `\` if you need it in the end result...

```
preg_match('/\\*.*?\\*/','dddd *ssssdedc* ddddddd',$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

gives...

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(10) "*ssssdedc*"
}
```

Comment: @Konstantinos Is there any reason that you haven't awarded this answer the big green tick?  This resolves the question in a refined manner as far as I am concerned.